# Rate Dimensions en ConstrainsDimensions esconde la imagen al escalar

Tags: android

1- Estoy aprendiendo android y siguendo un video, a la hora de dar proporciones a una imagen, tiene un comportamiento inesperado que no puedo resolver desde hace algunos días.
Al poner las proporciones 2:3 para el ancho de la imagen, esto se aplica cuando la imagen no tiene **constrain**, pero cuando le aplico los **constrain**, la imagen desaparece en un solo plano.
Estoy buscando en la web pero no encuentro ha nadie que comente este problema.
Cuando pongo el ratio son constrain alguno, o sólo top y bottom, la imagen se dimensiona con rate sin problema, pero cuando le pongo el constrain latera ya no.

2- Al mismo tiempo no veo claro cual es la sintaxis para poner el ratio en el archivo XML. a veces lo veo como por ejemplo "16:9", otras como "W,16:9" o "w,16:9", cual actualmente la sintaxis aceptada?

Pongo unas fotos para ilustrar los problemnas que surgen en la primera cuestión.

- Aquí la imagen sin constrain se proporciona correctamente.
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Aquí también:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Si hago el constrain con la imagen de arriba también funciona:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Pero cuando hago el constrain con el "parent" entonces pierde la imagen, el ratio y solo se produce un plano sin que se vea la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]